# Trigger inheritance in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 triggers for a WPF TabItem control, both are identical except for this line:

```
 <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
```

Is there any way I can make the trigger for IsMouseOver inherit from IsSelected and simply add the additional setter?Could you please provide an example if something like this is possible

**Complete XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't think what are asking for could be possible. There is a workaround using `MultiTrigger`.

Comment: a bit off topic: the following may explain why is it not possible to simply remove this duplication: http://www.paulstovell.com/six-years-of-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers don't inherit from each other.  What you're trying to do isn't possible.

You can have styles inherit from each other, but not triggers.