# DataTrigger EnterActions does not work without a setter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, storyboard, datatrigger

Really weird situation in WPF here... Let's say we have these code in a Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="In" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Out" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Checked}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Out}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource In}"/>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <!--<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{x:Null}"/>-->
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource style}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox bound to MainWindow.Checked property"
              IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Checked}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Tick above should hide me"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And there is a dependency property in MainWindow.cs named `Checked`. Plain and simple:

```
public bool Checked {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CheckedProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Basically the `TextBlock` should hide when the `CheckBox` is checked. BUT...

**The above code does not work unless I uncomment the `Setter` for `Tag`!** (Actually doesn't have to be Tag but any Setter will do.)

And it **does** work without uncommenting if I set the `Style` directly in `TextBlock` like this:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Tick above should hide me" Style="{StaticResource style}"/>
```

Can anyone explain this weird behavior? Am I experiencing some kind of bug in the Framework?

Comment: Because [triggers don't inherit from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726191/trigger-inheritance-in-wpf). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757436/inherited-wpf-style-with-triggers-doesnt-work) might be a solution, but I didn't try it

Comment: But it works if I include a Setter in the DataTrigger...

Comment: Just spotted that if you move the `tag` assignment before the trigger, the workaround stops to work